# Implementing equality function with basic arithmetic operations

Tags: math, arithmetic-expressions, integer-arithmetic

Given positive-integer inputs `x` and `y`, is there a mathematical formula that will return `1` if `x`==`y` and `0` otherwise? I am in the unfortunate position of having to use a tool that only allows me to use the following symbols: numerals `0`-`9`; decimal point `.`; parentheses `(` and `)`; and the four basic arithmetic operations `+`, `-`, `/`, and `*`.

Currently I am relying on the fact that the tool that evaluates division by zero to be zero. (I can't tell if this is a bug or a feature.) Because of this, I have been able to use `((x-y)/(y-x))+1`. Obviously, this is ugly and unideal, especially in the case that it is a bug and they fix it in a future version.

Comment: Nope.  Math doesn't work like that (your expression there, `((x-y)/(y-x))+1` should actually throw a divide-by-zero error if `x` and `y` are equal).

Comment: @Draco18s not in math, but in OP's tool; see OP's last paragraph!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I missed that.  If that's the case, then `((x-y)/(y-x))+1` would be the only way.

Comment: by the way, that's an extremely clever approach, Jeremiah!

Comment: um, what *awesome* tool are you using?

Comment: Since this is not a math site, can the solution take advantage of using integer math as defined by a computer language?

Comment: @chux, considering there's a decimal point available: probably not.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  the inputs are integers.  Using DP is optional.

Comment: Dear OP, **we need clarification**.

Comment: The tool in question is a form-builder (ugh…), and I wish I could tell you which language its math-evaluation is running in, but it's seeming to me that it's evaluating/validating it both client-side (JavaScript) and server-side. (Sorry for the delay; I was busy for a while.)

Comment: @JeremiahMegel: The question is whether 3/2 is 1 or 1.5.

Comment: There is no truncation. So 3/2 == 1.5

Comment: JeremiahMegel: Ah. In that case, I fear that @MarcusMüller is correct and there is no solution. (Unless you would be satisfied by x==y being 1 and x!=y being positive but less than 1, and I suspect that won't fit your use case.)

Comment: If this is purely a mathematical question, why post here rather than http://math.stackexchange.com/?  What is the programming aspect of this post?

Comment: @chux I considered it, but I felt that its nature was more in the computer-science area of mathematics, and that programmers might have more experience with this sort of problem than general mathematicians.

Comment: In programming, there is non-perfect math, like `1.0/3.0` --> `0.33333333333333331482961625...` rather than `.3333...` and integer math `1/3` --> `0`.  So if you want theory, go to the math site (and I think there is then no solution), yet if you want programming, tag the post of the programming language of interest.  Else I assert `(x/y) * (y/x)` is a fine programming solution using integer math.

Comment: The thing is: I don't for sure know which programming language is going to be evaluating this. I know that JavaScript is going to be doing it client-side, but I have no idea about server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of integer division in C truncates toward 0, the follows works well.  No multiplication overflow.  Well defined for all "positive-integer inputs `x` and `y`".

**`(x/y) * (y/x)`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void etest(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  unsigned ref = x == y;
  unsigned z =  (x/y) * (y/x);
  if (ref != z) {
    printf("%u %u %u %u\n", x,y,z,ref);
  }
}

void etests(void) {
  unsigned list[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,100,1000, UINT_MAX/2 , UINT_MAX - 1, UINT_MAX };
  for (unsigned x = 0; x < sizeof list/sizeof list[0]; x++) {
    for (unsigned y = 0; y < sizeof list/sizeof list[0]; y++) {
      etest(list[x], list[y]);
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {
  etests();
  printf("Done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output (No difference from `x == y`)

```
Done
```

Comment: Very nice. I don't know that the complexity of my solution is justified by the fact that it works even if x or y are 0.

Comment: @rici Thanks, Did not sound like `x,y==0` was important.  Easy to adjust here with `((x+1)/(y+1)) * ((y+1)/(x+1))`, but now loose use of `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: that just shifts the problem from 0 to -1 :) Using the square of the difference works with any values at all, as long as you can deal with overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If division is truncating and the numbers are not too big, then:

```
((x - y) ^ 2 + 2) / ((x - y) ^ 2 + 1) - 1
```

The division has the value 2 if x = y and otherwise truncates to 1.

(Here x^2 is an abbreviation for x*x.)

This will fail if (x-y)^2 overflows. In that case, you need to independently check `x/k = y/k` and `x%k = y%k` where `(k-1)*(k-1)` doesn't overflow (which will work if k is `ceil(sqrt(INT_MAX))`). `x%k` can be computed as `x-k*(x/k)` and `A&&B` is simply `A*B`.

That will work for any x and y in the range `[-k*k, k*k]`.

A slightly incorrect computation, using lots of intermediate values, which assumes that `x - y` won't overflow (or at least that the overflow won't produce a false 0).

```
  int delta = x - y;
  int delta_hi = delta / K;
  int delta_lo = delta - K * delta_hi;
  int equal_hi = (delta_hi * delta_hi + 2) / (delta_hi * delta_hi + 1) - 1;
  int equal_lo = (delta_lo * delta_lo + 2) / (delta_lo * delta_lo + 1) - 1;
  int equals = equal_hi * equal_lo;
```

or written out in full:

```
((((x-y)/K)*((x-y)/K)+2)/(((x-y)/K)*((x-y)/K)+1)-1)*
((((x-y)-K*((x-y)/K))*((x-y)-K*((x-y)/K))+2)/
 (((x-y)-K*((x-y)/K))*((x-y)-K*((x-y)/K))+1)-1)
```

(For signed 31-bit integers, use K=46341; for unsigned 32-bit integers, 65536.)

Checked with @chux's test harness, adding the 0 case: [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b8d315018274dd2) and with negative values [also on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8d65673c4ca478c).

On a platform where integer subtraction might produce something other than the 2s-complement wraparound, a similar technique could be used, but dividing the numbers into three parts instead of two.

Comment: Minor nits: `signed delta = x - y;` can incur signed overflow. `46341` depends on `int` being 32-bit.

Comment: @chux: Nits noted. :) I did actually generate the correct expression using cpp, but it's ridiculous to post, so I left it as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that if they fix division by zero, it means that you cannot use any divisor that contains input variables anymore (you'd have to check that the divisor != 0, and implementing that check would solve the original x-y == 0 problem!); hence, division cannot be used at all.

Ergo, only `+`, `-`, `*` and the association operator `()` can be used. It's not hard to see that with only these operators, the desired behaviour cannot be implemented.

Comment: "you'd have to check that the divisor != 0,"  --> it is known `x,y` are positive.

Comment: "It's not hard to see that with only these operators, the desired behaviour cannot be implemented." Apparently, that proposition is not as obvious as it might have appeared :-)

Comment: @rici I was assuming that the math involved pretty much operates "normally" over the field of  rational numbers, with the zero-division exception, and is not integer arithmetic. in fact, OP never stated such, and so I stand by that assumption until OP explains what he meant :)